# How to implement SOAP?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have to implement SOAP via HTTP, using C#.
Do you know any good documents, and sample code to help?

Comment: I means I need to handle the actual SOAP protocol, generate SOAP message by my self.
This is my exercise.

Comment: Is this for a class? Because outside of a class, nobody would do this.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you won't need to handle the actual SOAP protocol. If you have access to the WSDL document, Visual Studio will automatically build a proxy for your SOAP web service.

After that, you simply access the generated object's members as if it were a local object.

Check [this link](http://my.execpc.com/~gopalan/dotnet/webservices/webservice_csharp_client.html) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.0 or higher: **use WCF** - it's the most current, most flexible way to implement SOAP communication.

See the WCF developer center here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

WCF gives you plenty of options how to send messages to a remote system - be it HTTP or TCP/IP or MSMQ - you got the choice.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to google, I have found the following:

http://www.w3schools.com/SOAP/soap_intro.asp - Some background

http://www.w3schools.com/soap/default.asp - Tutorials